# Php array iteration fail

Tags: php, arrays

i have an app where i save weekdays and business hours on MySql as follow:

```
0 10 22,1 10 22,2 10 22,4 10 22,5 10 22,6 10 22
```

The php array fetch this from Mysql as following formats

```
Array ( [open_hours] => 0 10 22,1 10 22,2 10 22,4 10 22,5 10 22,6 10 22 )
```

`0 10 22` simply means `Monday 10am 22pm`

My current code seems not works well, below are the code i use to format the date and time

```
$openHrs = $businessMapper->getBusinessHours($business_id);
// return Array ( [open_hours] => 0 10 22,1 10 22,2 10 22,4 10 22,5 10 22,6 10 22 )
$openHrs = explode(",", $openHrs['open_hours']);
$weekdays = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
        foreach($openHrs as &$temp) {
             //$temp = $weekdays[$temp[0]]
            $temp = explode(" ", $temp);
             //$temp = explode(" ", $temp);
            $temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? $temp[1] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[1] . 'am';
            $temp[2] = $temp[2] > 12 ? $temp[2] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[2] . 'am';
            $temp = $weekdays[$temp[0]] . ' ' . $temp[1] . ' ' . $temp[2];
        }
```

But the issues is, i only get one result which is `Sat 10am 10pm`. How can i fix my code? Thanks!!

Comment: What output _do_ you get?

Answer (score 1):

Issue : every time when foreach iterates it over writes the previous value ie `$temp` will contains only the last value.

Solution : Added a variable $res as array and assigned each value to it.

Try this :

```
$openHrs = $businessMapper->getBusinessHours($business_id);
// return Array ( [open_hours] => 0 10 22,1 10 22,2 10 22,4 10 22,5 10 22,6 10 22 )
$openHrs = explode(",", $openHrs['open_hours']);
$weekdays = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');
$res      = array();
        foreach($openHrs as &$temp) {
             //$temp = $weekdays[$temp[0]]
            $temp = explode(" ", $temp);
             //$temp = explode(" ", $temp);
            $temp[1] = $temp[1] > 12 ? $temp[1] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[1] . 'am';
            $temp[2] = $temp[2] > 12 ? $temp[2] - 12 . 'pm' : $temp[2] . 'am';
            $res[]   = $weekdays[$temp[0]] . ' ' . $temp[1] . ' ' . $temp[2];
        }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach($openHrs as &$temp)

you cannot use $temp  variable in your loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
$openHrs = $businessMapper->getBusinessHours($business_id);
$openHrs = explode(",", $openHrs['open_hours']);
$weekdays = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');

$resultArray = array();

foreach($openHrs as $temp) {
   $tempRecord = explode(" ", $temp);

   if (count($tempRecord) == 3) {
       $timeBegin = $tempRecord[1] > 12 ? $tempRecord[1] - 12. 'pm' : $tempRecord[1]. 'am';
       $timeEnd = $tempRecord [2] > 12 ? $tempRecord[2] - 12. 'pm' : $tempRecord[2]. 'am';
       $resultArray[] = "{$weekdays[$temp[0]]} {$timeBegin} {$timeEnd}";
   }
}
```